# google map api not rendering Poly line

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have tried everything but direction line are not showing i know there is a minor mistake that i am not seeing or understanding direction will show to the nearest marker but i put static two markers this project is smart car api integration sorry to put a short code before now i updated the full code

```
     var loc = [];
var locations_array = [];
var small_time = 0;
var destination;
function createMap() 
{
  var x = 42.358329;
  var y = -71.056623;
  const KEY = "AIzaSyAPzNVajaVzHp6UQjk7-E7wu6DUPSx-E8A";

  var loc_latlng = 
  [
    [42.359130,-71.055250],
    [42.360950,-71.054920],
    [42.360280, -71.057140],
    [42.357360,-71.060690],
    [42.348860, -71.064780],
    [40.02049, -105.25620],
    [42.348860,-71.064780],
    [42.352050, -71.068320],
    [42.348300,-71.077610],
    [42.349232, -71.079529],
    [42.348470, -71.083710],
    [42.346570, -71.083840],
    [42.348180, -71.080710],
    [39.77277, -104.79596],
    [42.360950,-71.054920]
  ];

  var locations = 
  [
    '20 Clinton St Boston Massachusetts 02109',
    '26 North St Boston MA 02109',
    '90 Tremont St Boston MA 92108',
    '821 Washington St Boston MA 02111',
    '1710 29th St, Boulder, CO 80301, United States',
    '100 Stuart St Boston MA 02116',
    '200 Boylston St Boston MA 02116',
    '10 Huntington Ave Boston Massachusetts 02116',
    '61 Exeter St Boston MA 02116',
    '800 Boylston Street Boston Massachusetts 02199',
    '39 Dalton St Boston MA 02199',
    '776 Boylston St Boston Massachusetts 02199',
    '4310 Airport Way, Denver, CO 80239, United States',
    '20 Clinton St Boston Massachusetts 02109'  ];

  var origin1 = {lat: x , lng: y};
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin1],
    destinations:  locations,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status) 
    {
      if (status == 'OK') 
      {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {
          zoom: 17,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(origin1),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
          map: map,
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(origin1),
          map: map,
        });

        var nearest_time = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < response.rows[0].elements.length; i++) 
        {
          if(nearest_time == 0)
          {
            nearest_time = response.rows[0].elements[i].duration.value;
          }

          if(nearest_time > response.rows[0].elements[i].duration.value)
          {
            var destination = {lat: loc_latlng[i][0] , lng: loc_latlng[i][1]};

            // marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            // {
              // position: new google.maps.LatLng(small_time),
              // map: map,
            // });
          }
        }

        console.log(destination);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(destination),
          map: map,
        });


        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var request = 
        {
          origin: origin1,
          destination: destination,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) 
        {
          if (status == 'OK') 
          {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
          }
        });
      }
    });





}

createMap();

function createMarker(origin1,small_time)
{


  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var request = 
    {
      origin: origin1 ,
      destination: small_time,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
      transitOptions: {
      departureTime: new Date(1337675679473),
      modes: ['BUS'],
      routingPreference: 'FEWER_TRANSFERS'
    }
  };

  // marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (there is no `map` in the posted code)

Comment: updated the full code

Comment: <div class="col">
        <div id="map" style="height:700px; width:1200px;"></div>
      </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding your `directionRenderer` to the map:

```
var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/n61qp089/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var loc = [];
var locations_array = [];
var small_time = 0;
var destination;

function createMap() {
  var x = 42.358329;
  var y = -71.056623;
  const KEY = "AIzaSyAPzNVajaVzHp6UQjk7-E7wu6DUPSx-E8A";

  var loc_latlng = [
    [42.359130, -71.055250],
    [42.360950, -71.054920],
    [42.360280, -71.057140],
    [42.357360, -71.060690],
    [42.348860, -71.064780],
    [40.02049, -105.25620],
    [42.348860, -71.064780],
    [42.352050, -71.068320],
    [42.348300, -71.077610],
    [42.349232, -71.079529],
    [42.348470, -71.083710],
    [42.346570, -71.083840],
    [42.348180, -71.080710],
    [39.77277, -104.79596],
    [42.360950, -71.054920]
  ];

  var locations = [
    '20 Clinton St Boston Massachusetts 02109',
    '26 North St Boston MA 02109',
    '90 Tremont St Boston MA 92108',
    '821 Washington St Boston MA 02111',
    '1710 29th St, Boulder, CO 80301, United States',
    '100 Stuart St Boston MA 02116',
    '200 Boylston St Boston MA 02116',
    '10 Huntington Ave Boston Massachusetts 02116',
    '61 Exeter St Boston MA 02116',
    '800 Boylston Street Boston Massachusetts 02199',
    '39 Dalton St Boston MA 02199',
    '776 Boylston St Boston Massachusetts 02199',
    '4310 Airport Way, Denver, CO 80239, United States',
    '20 Clinton St Boston Massachusetts 02109'
  ];

  var origin1 = {
    lat: x,
    lng: y
  };
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin1],
    destinations: locations,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(origin1),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
      });

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(origin1),
        map: map,
      });

      var nearest_time = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < response.rows[0].elements.length; i++) {
        if (nearest_time == 0) {
          nearest_time = response.rows[0].elements[i].duration.value;
        }

        if (nearest_time > response.rows[0].elements[i].duration.value) {
          var destination = {
            lat: loc_latlng[i][0],
            lng: loc_latlng[i][1]
          };

          // marker = new google.maps.Marker(
          // {
          // position: new google.maps.LatLng(small_time),
          // map: map,
          // });
        }
      }

      console.log(destination);

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(destination),
        map: map,
      });


      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
      });
      var request = {
        origin: origin1,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      };

      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
    }
  });





}

function createMarker(origin1, small_time) {


  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var request = {
    origin: origin1,
    destination: small_time,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    transitOptions: {
      departureTime: new Date(1337675679473),
      modes: ['BUS'],
      routingPreference: 'FEWER_TRANSFERS'
    }
  };

  // marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=createMap">
</script>
```